# Array To Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, arrays, binary-search-tree

I need to create a function that creates a BST from an array, in python. The array is already sorted.

The example is:

```
function array_to_binary_search_tree(array, start, end)
    if start > end
        Return an empty value
    mid := int((start + end) / 2)
    tree := BinaryTree()
    tree.node := array[mid]
    tree.left := array_to_binary_search_tree(array, start, mid - 1)
    tree.right := array_to_binary_search_tree(array, mid + 1, end)
    Return 'tree'
```

I have this:

```
class BST:

def __init__(self,tree,info):
    self.right = None
    self.left = None
    self.info = info

    def arrayToBST(seq):
    if (seq == []):
        return None
    mid = ((len(seq)) // 2)
    tree = BST(seq[mid])
    tree.left = arrayToBST(seq[0:mid])
    tree.right = arrayToBST(seq[mid+1:])

    return tree

if __name__ == "__main__":
    seq = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    arrayToBST(seq)
```

The result is:

> > > NameError: name 'arrayToBST' is not defined

I don't see the error. Please help, thanks!

Comment: arrayToBST is a member of a class. You need to call it from one instance of this class

Comment: where is your object of the Class BST?

Comment: try using: `BST().arrayToBST(seq)`

Answer (score 1):

In your recursive call, you are calling the `arrayToBST` method of an instance. Therefore, you need to call `self.arrayToBST` not just `arryToBST`. The entire point of `self` is to let you access attributes on your instance.

You should also create an instance and call that instance's `arrayToBST` method in your main section.